# AutoCompleteTextView or SearchDialog?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-widget

What i need to be done are just the suggestions of keywords can be clicked and bring user to the interfaces (xml layout). For example the result below abide, abound, absence. I created them in R.layout.abide

Though `AutoCompleteTextView` seem to be less hassle but can it be done ? Or the only way to do it is through `SearchDialog`? I am not using `SearchWidget` because i am doing api level 8.

[image]

Comment: your question is not clear so be specific and clear about what you want....

Comment: I am putting a function into my application which user input keywords, suggestions works like the AutoCompleteTextView and these suggestions has to be clickable and take you to their page which i already created. Is this clear enough yet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I am not wrong,you want user to just select an item from AutoComplete and once he selects it,it should bring you to another activity.if it is the case then you can achieve it as below.

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.autocomplete_item,options);
 // R.layout.autocomplete_item is custom spinner item xml file.you can use default spinner item also.
autoComplete.setAdapter(adapter); 
autoComplete.setThreshold(1);
autoComplete.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,
                    long arg3) {

        Intent intent;
        int index=999;
        for(int i=0;i<options.length;i++)
        {
            if(options[i].equals(autoComplete.getText().toString().trim()))
            {
                index=i;
                break;
            }
        }
        switch(index)
        {
            case 0:
                intent=new Intent(ThisActivity.this,ActivityZero.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                break;
            case 1:
                intent=new Intent(ThisActivity.this,ActivityOne.class);
                startActivity(intent);   
                break; 
                ...         
        }
    }
});
```

Or if you want to stay on the same activity but want to change its xml according to the selection user makes in AutoComplete then you can setContentView(your xml); in above cases for various selection.

Comment: The autocomplete_item of yours, i am having mine as the list_item.xml from here http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-autocomplete.html.

As for the switch, i am very newbie in java as well. Why isit AcitivityZero.class ? Because my layouts are in .xml only.

Comment: I hope,you know the concept of Activity and Layout..If no,then please refer http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html for activity and http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html for xml concepts.

Comment: there was a mistake in previous one.so please follow my updated answer.

Comment: I am thinking to have setContentView(R.layout.mylayout); inside the switch case.

Comment: So do i still keeping this or remove?
>static final String[] SHOP = new String[]
 {
   "mylayout1", "mylayout2"
 };

Comment: Yes, finaly someone understood my requirement. Thank you so much. Keep this question updated until i complete my function.

Comment: Please check my update in answer.made it autoComplete.getText().toString().trim();

Comment: Ok Hiral i cant put my source here, can you have a look. I marked the errors. Can you go to this link? I will tick the answer once everything has sorted out. Much appreciated. http://www.mediafire.com/?88orxml57so0bdf