# Local variable may not been initialized

Tags: java, android

How do i initialized autoComplete? I cant use it with AutoCompleteTextView because it'll tell me that local variable is duplicated. Tried declaring it static as well but its not permitted.

Please advice!

```
public class Search extends Activity {
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceSate) {
        final int autoComplete;
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceSate);
        setContentView(R.layout.searchshop);

         //The duplicate im talking about
        AutoCompleteTextView autoCompletee = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView1);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, shops);
        autoCompletee.setAdapter(adapter); 
        autoCompletee.setThreshold(1);
        autoCompletee.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3)  {
                Intent intent;
                int index=999;
                for(int i=0;i<shops.length;i++) {
                        //The local variable autoComplete may not been initialized
                    if(shops[i].equals(Integer.toString(autoComplete))) {
                        index=i;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                switch(index) {
                    case 0:
                        intent=new Intent(Search.this, Adidas.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        intent=new Intent(Search.this, Affin.class);
                        startActivity(intent);  
                        break; 
                }
            }
        }); 
    }

    static final String[] shops = new String[] {
                "Adidas", "Affin Bank", "Alam Art", "Al Amin"
    };
}
```

Comment: this makes no sense.  You have an int variable called autoComplete which is never assigned any value.  So of course it is not initialized.  What's your question?

Comment: The answer depends a great deal on what value you would like your `autoComplete` to have.

Comment: The question is not so much the how, but the why. As far as I can see, the variable isn't used except in one `equals` call, which always returns false.

Comment: Sorry for any confusion i am new in this. Previously autoComplete was initialized with AutoCompleteTextView but that would led to "Cannot refer to a non-final variable autoComplete inside an inner class defined in a different method." And once i declare autoComplete with final, it tells me i have variable duplication.

Any of you can head over here and have a look?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8997684/autocompletetextview-or-searchdialog/

Answer (score 0):

Modifying the `int autoComplete` to be `static`, `final`, etc won't matter one bit because the compiler is complaining about the fact that you already have a variable called "autoComplete". In your actual code example, you named your `AutoCompleteTextView` "autoCompletee" with two e's which is different from `autoComplete` so that will work. But I'd recommend using more meaningful variable names like `int autoCompleteValue` or something along those lines. Either way, the problem is that you have variables colliding. Once you have a variable in scope with a certain name, you cannot use that name again...

Answer (score -1):

You have autoComplete field as local variable, which need to set to some default value.

just set `final int autoComplete=0;`

Move this as third statement in code, first two statements should be super.... and setContent(...)

Comment: and he's going to have a variable which is always equal to 0?  What for?

Comment: What for? OP knows. The issue in question is, local variable is not initialed, which will be resolved by answer. Answer is to the question. Doesn't make sense downvote. In the code, there is no case of assigning some value to auto complete.

Comment: OP is confused and you are not helping to unconfuse him.

Comment: I won't downvote you but I can see why others would. Yes, you gave an answer but your answer is not helping and has no practical value either to the OP or the general public. (It's not entirely your fault, the question itself is a bit messed up, but still.)

Comment: @MK, in my view it is step process, I guess OP is learning, as he resolve the issue one by one, learns. My view, let developer come up with question, why we need this, than we decide. Without fixing local variable issue, it will add more confusion if we initiate another discussion, why we that variable there. Anyways, it is my perspective.

Comment: I think your answer should at least mention that this line of code makes no sense as autoComplete will always be just a 0.